# Raycasts in unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a script that will make a game object move along a raycast when it detects something, and for some reason, something in 3d is happening and messing up the raycasts direction

'''

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CreatureActivity : MonoBehaviour
{
    float sense = 2;
    float speed = .05f;
    LayerMask LayerMask = 8;

    private void Start()
    {
        Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);

        Vector2 right = new Vector2(position.x + 1, position.y);
        Vector2 left = new Vector2(position.x - 1, position.y);
        Vector2 up = new Vector2(position.x, position.y + 1);
        Vector2 down = new Vector2(position.x, position.y - 1);

        RaycastHit2D hitInfoR = Physics2D.Raycast(position, right, sense);
        RaycastHit2D hitInfoL = Physics2D.Raycast(position, left, sense);
        RaycastHit2D hitInfoU = Physics2D.Raycast(position, up, sense);
        RaycastHit2D hitInfoD = Physics2D.Raycast(position, down, sense);
        //right ray
        if (hitInfoR.collider != null)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, right, speed);
            Debug.DrawLine(position, hitInfoR.point, Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(position, position + right * 2, Color.green);
        }
        
        //left ray
        if (hitInfoL.collider != null)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(position, left, speed);
            Debug.DrawLine(position, hitInfoR.point, Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(position, position + left * 2, Color.green);
        }
        //up ray
        if (hitInfoU.collider != null)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(position, up, speed);
            Debug.DrawLine(position, hitInfoR.point, Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(position, position + up * 2, Color.green);
        }
        //down ray
        if (hitInfoD.collider != null)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(position, down, speed);
            Debug.DrawLine(position, hitInfoR.point, Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(position, position + down * 2, Color.green);
        }
        
    }
}
```

'''
you can ignore this part stack overflow wants me to add more details but I don't know what else to add.

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake is: [`Vector2.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) expects as parameters a **current position** and a **target position** .. **not a direction**.

Instead of e.g.

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, right, speed);
```

you would rather use

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(position, position + right, speed);
```

Now this is still wrong though! What if your hit is closer? The before mentioned solution might overshoot. So you would rather use the actual maximal target position and simply use

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(position, hitInfoR.point, speed);
```

---

Some further notes though

- What if multiple of your raycasts hit something?

  → you would rather make one Raycast check at a time and stop after the first one that hits.
- And you know btw that there already exist `Vector2.up`, `Vector2.down`, `Vector2.right` and `Vector2.left`?
- And in general `Vector2 is a struct` and stored **by value** so a line like

  ```
  Vector2 position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
  ```

  is quite redundant .. just do

  ```
  Vector2 position = transform.position;
  ```